# Infragistics data chart C# WPF highlight part of a series

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, stackedbarseries, xamdatachart

I have a listview box which contains my data, it is loaded when selected into a infragistics data chart, it is all loaded into a single stacked bar series. What I now need to be able to do is click one segment of the bar series and be able to highlight and zoom in.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is still not clear. Also post part of your code where you're stuck.

Comment: Be specific and clear what you ask.So that others can help you

Comment: I have a list of data displayed in a listview and it is also in a single stacked bar series in an infragistics xamdatachart on the same dialog. At the point of selecting an item in the listview, I need it to zoom in on that part of the stacked series and highlight it. Does this help?

Comment: Check this: [Hot Tracking](https://www.infragistics.com/samples/windows-forms/chart/hot-tracking)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using `Bar/ColumnSeries` to display single stacked bars.
To highlight you can make use of `ChartAnnotationLayers` to highlight a particular value & hence the bar by setting the `MarkerTemplate` property.
Also you can set a default value or override it on hover.

The documentation [here](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/datachart-categoryitemhighlightlayer) can help.